# XSLT: Is there any way to convert a generic xml file to csv?

Tags: linux, unix, csv, xml, xslt

I have a few XML files with different structures without XSD and I need to convert them to CSV, including the headers. The headers should be the "dot" concatenation of the path for the single element. For example:

```
<root>
  <item>
    <subitem>
      foo
    </subitem>
etc..
```

the header will be: `root.item.subitem`

Is there any "generic" converter to CSV in XSLT or alternatives to XSLT self?

Comment: You need a much more careful specification of what range of inputs you want to handle, and what output you want to produce from them. To take a random example, how would you expect the data in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38886913/saxon-he-9-7-xquery-results-and-existing-document/38891244#38891244 to look when converted to CSV?

Comment: The only thing I can tell is that I dont have to care about any attribute for the single tag. I need only the text value extracted from the single leaf. I dont know all the tag names and the potential structure for the single one.

Comment: XML is hierarchic. A document representing an SO question, say, would contain one question, many answers, and each question and answer would have many comments. That structure isn't easy to represent in CSV. If you don't know how you would represent a hierarchic structure in CSV, then you can't produce a generic XML-to-CSV converter.

Comment: Well if you recursively  isolate all the distinct xpaths then apply them to the xml self you should be able to do that (not considering attributes)

Comment: @Randomize: What about mixed elements?  Elements that contain both text and sub-elements.  Such as `<item>This has text <a>and</a> other things.<sub_item>Hello!</sub_item></item>`  That would be a right mess using the approach you mention.